# Limit of inverse system where morphisms are non-zero products

Tags: modules, homological-algebra

I have a rather complicated inverse limit which I am trying to compute. I will try to distil the question to its barest form, but if more details are necessary I can supply them.

Let $R$ be an integral domain and equip $\mathbb N$ with the usual ordering. Consider an inverse system $(A_i, f_{ij})_{\mathbb N}$ in $\text{Mod}_R$ defined by 
$$f_{i,i+1}: A_{i+1} \to A_i, \quad a \mapsto r_{i+1} a, \qquad r_i \neq 0,1.$$
I would like to determine $\varprojlim A_i$.

Things seem to be as nice as possible: we're in a bicomplete category so we know the limit should exist, the directed system is totally ordered, etc. However, in trying to construct an element of this limit, it seems like every component must consist of an infinite product of the $r_i$'s. Does this mean that the only element of this limit is zero, and hence that $\varprojlim A_i = 0$?

Edit: Very little may be assumed about the $r_i$. For example, we do not know if they are units, and even if they are, we do not know whether their inverses appear in any morphism.

Comment: What are the $A_i$? Copies of the same module?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had answered this question before but I guess it didn't stick. I would prefer to take them as nested submodules of some fixed module. If you like, you can take them as being the same module.

Edit: Also if it helps, we know that $r_{i+1} \in (r_i)$.

Answer (score 0):

The inverse limit is not zero. You have a functor $A: \mathbb{N}^{op} \to Mod_R$, and you want a module that satisfies the universal property. The module:

$$ \{ x \in \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N} } A_n | x_n = f_{n,m}(x_m) \ for \  all  \ n \leq m   \} $$

has the universal property of the inverse limit, so this is isomorphic to the inverse limit.

The elements are not infinite products, but infinite vectors indexed by the natural numbers.

Also, this construction does not depend of the index set neither the ring (you can take any ring not necessarily commutative, with unit).

Comment: And it is easy to check that if all the $f_n=0$, then the inverse limit is the zero module.

Comment: All you have done is regurgitate the definition of the inverse limit on algebraic objects. Did you check what the morphisms do? That is the problem.

Choose an element $(a_n)$ and let's see what conditions $a_1$ must satisfy. By definition, for any $n$ we have $f_{1n} = f_{12} \cdots f_{n-1,n}$, so that 
$$a_1=f_{1n}(a_n) = \left(\prod_{i=1}^n r_i \right) a_n.$$ 
Without information on the $r_i$, we cannot assume the product reduces, so $a_1$ is an $n$-fold product (of ring elements), *for each $n$*. Hence an infinite product.

Comment: Commutativity is a simplifying assumption so that we do not need to discuss left vs right vs two-sided modules. The construction does depend on both the ring and index set: If the module admits torsion, we're in a different situation since the stabilizing property could collapse to zero, and your construction above is not true if the limit is not filtered.

Comment: Finally, what use is the statement "And it is easy to check that if all the fn=0, then the inverse limit is the zero module?" This is irrelevant. There are plenty of examples of non-zero objects with non-zero morphisms which admit empty/zero limits. [Waterhouse 1972 - Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 36 (1972), 618 ] is an excellent and simple example.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I didn't see the definition of the $f_n$'s. Sorry.